# How can I connect Xamarin Android app to an existing Sqlite database?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I developed the Xamarin android app. I also created an Sqlite database using Sqlite browser. After that, I inserted my existing data. My database has 5 tables. Now I want to connect to it via my Xamarin Android app. How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find a nice tutorial to use the SQLite database in your Xamarin.Android project [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AVPhip842M)

Alternatively you can use the SQLite.Net library to connect with the database, you can find the detailed documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/)

Comment: Actually  i want to SQLite database connect Xamarin app. And also want to database handle for using Sqlite browser. But where my database create? What location store my database? I can't find it.

Comment: string dbPath = Path.Combine (
        Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
        "ormdemo.db3"); This is database path. But how can i find this location. Where store "ormdemo.db3" database. I can't find it.Please help me.

Comment: I can manually create "example.db3" using sqlite browser. Then how can pack it my xamarin app. What is the connection string.

Comment: @Sampath You can have to add it as an asset under Resources/Assets folder, when the runs for the first time copy it over to `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` path

Comment: please give me a sample code or link. I try it. But does not working. My existing database firstly copy Assest folder. After set the path. But not solved problem. Give me a some advice.

Comment: Hi @Sampath, maybe this link can help you as it includes a complete code example along with detailed explanation: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/837061/Xamarin-plus-SQlite-plus-Android